# Как показать div скрытый под div position:absolute

Tags: html5, css3

Здравствуйте,

столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть изображение **div.row1 img** высота его не известна и она меняется в зависимости от ширина экрана. Есть блок с контентом **div.row2** высота этого блока так же не известна.

Подскажите пожалуйста как в данном случае сделать видимым **div.footer** не выбивая его из потока (не присваивая ему z-index и position)?

```css
.article {
  max-width: 1050px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 100%
}

.row2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  margin: 0 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px dotted #2F2F2F;
}

.footer {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
  <div class="row1"><img src="https://placehold.it/1100x200/E8117F/ffffff&amp;text=images" alt=""></div>
  <div class="row2" style="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">&copy; Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> relative - Относительное позиционирование. Положение элемента
>   устанавливается относительно его исходного места.

Т.е он остается в потоке.

```
.footer {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
```